# make many input into one string angular 6

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I make function like google verification code, user must input number that send to their email, and user must input that code into verification page
I make 6 input for user input their code like this:

---

[OTP PAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3oT7I.png)

and each that is a diffrent input field with diffrent name like input1, input2, input3, etc

I want make that diffrent name have just one name that have one value.
Like this 
input: (231486)

not like this
input1: (2)
input2: (3)
input3: (1)
etc

this my code:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="otp(otpForm.value)" [formGroup]="otpForm">
            <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center">
              <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tr>
                  <ng-container>
                    <td class="otp__tdr">
                      <mat-form-field class="otp__field">
                        <input
                          #input1
                          matInput
                          maxlength="1"
                          formControlName="otp1"
                          (input)="onInputEntry($event, input2)"
                        />
                      </mat-form-field>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <mat-form-field class="otp__field">
                        <input
                          #input2
                          matInput
                          maxlength="1"
                          formControlName="otp2"
                          (input)="onInputEntry($event, input3)"
                        />
                      </mat-form-field>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <mat-form-field class="otp__field">
                        <input
                          #input3
                          matInput
                          maxlength="1"
                          formControlName="otp3"
                          (input)="onInputEntry($event, input4)"
                        />
                      </mat-form-field>
                    </td>
          <button type="submit" mat-raised-button color="primary">
                Verify
              </button>
            </div>
          </form>
```

its some of my typescript:

```
export class OtpComponent implements OnInit {

  otpForm: FormGroup;
  // FormControl = new FormControl('');

  constructor( private router: Router, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.otpForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      otp1: ['', Validators.required],
      otp2: ['', Validators.required],
      otp3: ['', Validators.required],
      otp4: ['', Validators.required],
      otp5: ['', Validators.required],
      otp6: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }

  onInputEntry(event, nextInput) {
    const input = event.target;
    const length = input.value.length;
    const maxLength = input.attributes.maxlength.value;

    if (length >= maxLength) {
      nextInput.focus();
    }
  }

  otp(otpForm) {
    console.log('test otp', otpForm);
  }
```

can someone help me thanks for the help

Comment: Please include the code you have tried.

Comment: Uh, it's just a single textbox with CSS?

Comment: I already make my typescript

Answer (score 4):

There's nothing special about the inputs, just apply SCSS to your input:

```
$num-of-char: 6;
$char-width: 1ch;
$gap: .4 * $char-width;
$in-w: $num-of-char * ($char-width + ($gap));

input {
    display: block;
    border: none;
    width: $in-w;
    background: repeating-linear-gradient(90deg, 
        #000 0, #000 $char-width, 
        transparent 0, transparent $char-width + $gap) 
        0 100%/ #{$in-w - $gap} 2px no-repeat;
    font: 5ch droid sans mono, consolas, monospace;
    letter-spacing: $gap;

    &:focus {
        outline: none;
    }
}
```

`<input maxlength='6' value='231486'/>`

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-beo6ar)  example

Comment: but I must use angular material

Answer (score 0):

try with a loop with formGroup array using forEach

```
let inputData: string = '';

Object.keys(this.otpForm.controls).forEach((key) => {
       inputData += this.otpForm.get(key).value();
});
```

alternatively, you can use `for..of` and later join the array

```
const inputData = [];
for (const field in this.otpForm.controls) {
   const inputvalue = this.otpForm.get(field).value(); 
   inputData.concat(inputvalue);
}
```

Comment: whats a "field" mean in {const field in this.otpform.controls}

Comment: field will take each fon control value . in . your case it would be opt1, opt2 and so on.. you can console the same

Answer (score 0):

You need to have couple of variables first the actual string value and second one which will keep each character of string value into an array. This array will be used to bind the input value through ngModel.

```
  varifyNumber = "231486";
  numbers = new Array(6);

  ngOnInit(){
     this.numbers = this.varifyNumber.split("");
  }

  public getVerifyNumber(){
    return this.numbers.join("");
  }
```

Here is the working demo - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z9hkfp